# what are the roles of synchronous and asyncronuos interfaces in a GWT RPC .can anyone explain it in detail?

Tags: gwt, rpc

what are the roles of synchronous and asynchronous interfaces in a GWT RPC .can anyone explain it in detail?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> [The] synchronous interface is the definitive version of your service's specification. Any implementation of this service on the server-side must extend `RemoteServiceServlet` and implement this service interface.
>
> […]
>
> It is not possible to call this version of the RPC directly from the client. You must create an asynchronous interface to all your services […]
>
> […]
>
> Before you can actually attempt to make a remote call from the client, you must create another client interface, an asynchronous one, based on your original service interface.
>
> […]
>
> The nature of asynchronous method calls requires the caller to pass in a callback object that can be notified when an asynchronous call completes, since by definition the caller cannot be blocked until the call completes. For the same reason, asynchronous methods do not have return types; they generally return void. Should you wish to have more control over the state of a pending request, return `Request` instead. After an asynchronous call is made, all communication back to the caller is via the passed-in callback object.

*Source:* http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideCreatingServices

Comment: Thanks...I have another question.When we make an RPC call MyServiceAsyncObject.myMethod(params,callback_object) why doesn't the server get confused by seeing the extra parameter i.e callback object because it should expect myMethod(params) as per its implementation of the inerface MyService?

Comment: Because there's a big generated "machinery" and network in between the client and server? The GWT compiler verifies that the 2 interfaces match and generates client-side code that will talk the protocol understood by the server (which itself uses reflection on the interface and objects passed as arguments); that protocol is tightly bound to your objects and changing the order of your fields can break the communication, forcing you to recompile your app (regenerate the client-side code to match the code used on server side)